# DataGridTemplateColumn find no binding root

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, user-controls

I am trying to put a user control, named simpleChart, into a DataGridTemplateColumn. I bind the DataGrid to an `ObservableCollection<Index>` (where Index is an INotifyPropertyChanged class that I created for display). But somehow, the binding cannot find the root item. To check my binding, I put a textColumn aside the templateColumn, and it works just fine. Here is the relevant code:

```
<Window x:Class="TechniqueAnalysis.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="" Height="549" Width="1744" 
    xmlns:diagnostics="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Charts"
    xmlns:simpleChart ="clr-namespace:ChartOnGird;assembly=ChartOnGird"
    WindowState="Maximized" Closing="Window_Closing">
<Grid>
<DataGrid Margin="0,60,0,0" Name="dataGridWei" CanUserResizeColumns="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding}">
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="2 day"  Width="100">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <simpleChart:SimpleChart X ="{Binding Path=X1, diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Path=X1, diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High, StringFormat=N2}"/>
</DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

The databinding is through background code which binds the ObservableCollection to the datagrid's DataContext.

And I get the following output for the template column:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 : BindingExpression (hash=45649854): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 59 : BindingExpression (hash=45649854): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=45649854): Attach to ChartOnGird.SimpleChart.X (hash=40977533)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=45649854): Resolving source
System.Windows.Data Warning: 68 : BindingExpression (hash=45649854): Found data context element: SimpleChart (hash=40977533) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 76 : BindingExpression (hash=45649854): Activate with root item ''
System.Windows.Data Warning: 106 : BindingExpression (hash=45649854):   At level 0 - for String.X1 found accessor <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 106 : BindingExpression (hash=45649854):   At level 0 - for EnumerableCollectionView.X1 found accessor <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 102 : BindingExpression (hash=45649854): Replace item at level 0 with {NullDataItem}, using accessor {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=45649854): TransferValue - got raw value {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}
System.Windows.Data Warning: 86 : BindingExpression (hash=45649854): TransferValue - using fallback/default value '9'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 87 : BindingExpression (hash=45649854): TransferValue - using final value '9'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 54 : Created BindingExpression (hash=32948864) for Binding (hash=33575416)
```

But for the text column, I get the following warning:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 : BindingExpression (hash=32948864): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 59 : BindingExpression (hash=32948864): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=32948864): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.Text (hash=6303902)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=32948864): Resolving source
System.Windows.Data Warning: 68 : BindingExpression (hash=32948864): Found data context element: TextBlock (hash=6303902) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 69 : BindingExpression (hash=32948864): DataContext is null
System.Windows.Data Warning: 63 : BindingExpression (hash=32948864): Resolve source deferred
System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=8194399): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 68 : BindingExpression (hash=8194399): Found data context element: TextBlock (hash=33203677) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 76 : BindingExpression (hash=8194399): Activate with root item Index (hash=33903126)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 106 : BindingExpression (hash=8194399):   At level 0 - for Index.X1 found accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(X1)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 102 : BindingExpression (hash=8194399): Replace item at level 0 with Index (hash=33903126), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(X1)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 99 : BindingExpression (hash=8194399): GetValue at level 0 from Index (hash=33903126) using RuntimePropertyInfo(X1): '1'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=8194399): TransferValue - got raw value '1'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 82 : BindingExpression (hash=8194399): TransferValue - implicit converter produced '1.00'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 87 : BindingExpression (hash=8194399): TransferValue - using final value '1.00'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=32948864): Resolving source
System.Windows.Data Warning: 68 : BindingExpression (hash=32948864): Found data context element: TextBlock (hash=6303902) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 76 : BindingExpression (hash=32948864): Activate with root item Index (hash=49245678)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 105 : BindingExpression (hash=32948864):   At level 0 using cached accessor for Index.X1: RuntimePropertyInfo(X1)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 102 : BindingExpression (hash=32948864): Replace item at level 0 with Index (hash=49245678), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(X1)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 99 : BindingExpression (hash=32948864): GetValue at level 0 from Index (hash=49245678) using RuntimePropertyInfo(X1): '1'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=32948864): TransferValue - got raw value '1'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 82 : BindingExpression (hash=32948864): TransferValue - implicit converter produced '1.00'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 87 : BindingExpression (hash=32948864): TransferValue - using final value '1.00'
```

It seems that the templatecolumn fails to find a correct root item. The question is what is a proper way to help it to find the proper one? I tried to add an RelateSource but did not figure out how. My class "Index" is under the MainWindow class. Please help me.  I have spend 2 days on it. I believe I am almost there but there is just something that I cannot figure out without help.

Comment: Have you tried setting the type-property on the DataTemplate?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly do you mean. But I tried to add in the DataTemplate DataType = "simpleChart:simpleChart" or DataType = "local:Index"  after I move my class "Index" outside of MainWindow. Both of them do not help. I still get the exact the same output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is your simpleChart `UserControl`. Probably you set the `DataContext` for this control in the wrong manner and that's why the bindings will not find the `Row.DataContext` but rather the `UserControl.DataContext`.

Take a look at this [Simple Pattern for Creating Re-useable UserControls](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/02/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight/) to do it the right way.

Comment: I think you are probably right. But I am not sure how to do it even after reading the reading the page you linked. I original left DataContext alone. But after I specified the DataContext in my usercontrol: this.DataContext = this. It still found the data context element: SimpleChart, but now it actives with root item SimpleChart as I have specified. When I looked at the example you give, it also found the data context element as UserControl1, but the root item is the correct object ModelObject for some reason.

Comment: You are right, I placed a DataContext = "" in my control definition in XAML long time ago by mistake. That is why it give me so much trouble. Thanks.